# Network adapter failing when using node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, networking, tcp, wireshark

I'm having this super bizarre problem at work; I've made two small node.js programs that interact with each other via HTTP get and post requests. Program B monitors some text files and sends a post request to Program A anytime the files change (once a minute). After acknowledging that request, Program A then sends a post request to program B, which then writes another set of text files.

The computer that hosts program B, at some (unpredictable) point in the day, just stops getting proper network connection—we'd be unable to use the browser, unable to remote desktop, and the node program also can't communicate, logging with ECONNRESET errors. It can, however, ping other machines in the network and on the internet. We thought there was a problem with the network card so we actually switched the machine which runs Program B and we still have the same problem.

We've noticed this only happens when Node.js is running, and is actively sending https requests to and from program A. A restart is the only solution we've found that sets things back to normal.

Our next idea was to install Wireshark and see what's up. The first thing that we noticed is this on the 'info' field:

3000→53550 [RST, ACK] Seq=2 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0

It happens once every minute, and seems to be from the machine hosting Program A. Is this normal behavior? (Wireshark highlights it in red) Network communication is still normal at this point.

Eventually, it zero's out a TCP window and then things get worse:
[image: Zero TCP Window]

We started to see duplicate acknowledgements and lots of retransmissions being sent:
[image: Retransmissions]

and then finally the TCP window being full, and then reset:
[image]

Network communication fails at this point (except being able to ping).

I'm totally lost. I don't know whether this is a problem with my programming, or with node's implementation of network tools, or whether it's a driver / hardware issue, or a kernel issue.

We're running Windows 7 on both machines. Node 4.4.1

Any help or advice on what this could be would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here's the some code snippets regarding the sending and receiving of information in **Program B** (I'm using Express.js) .

Receiving:

```
app.post('/eton_call', function (req, res){
    logger.info("POST REQUEST: eton_call") //using winston.js to log things
    reqCalls_writer.write_file(req.body); //writes the text file in a certain format
    res.sendStatus(201);
})

app.post('/USERPRUN_call', function (req, res){
    logger.info("POST REQUEST: userprun_call")
    userPrun_writer.write_file(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(201);
})
```

Sending: (they all use this prototyped function. The argument, snapshot, is some JSON)

```
Eton_file_sync.prototype.send_snapshot = function(snapshot) {
    logger.info('sending snapshot');

    var post_options = {
        host: config.fex_server.host,
        port: config.fex_server.port,
        path: this.post_uri,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': snapshot.length
        }
    };

    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        logger.info("STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            logger.info('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    post_req.on('error', function(e){
        logger.error('Snapshot not sent. Please ensure connectivity to fex-server.js. This snapshot will be lost. Error Message: ' + e.message);
    })

    post_req.write(snapshot);
    post_req.end();
}
```

Here's the code for writing files

```
Eton_asc_writer.prototype.write_file = function (data_arr){

    logger.info("writing file");
    var buffer_data = '';
    data_arr.forEach(function (data_element, index, array){
        for (prop in data_element){
            _.find(this, function(template_element){//finds the template_element with the correct descriptions
                return template_element.description == prop; //^
            }).datum = data_element[prop];//copies over datum to template element
        }
        //finds the first then second then third.. nth field.
        for (var field_order = 1; field_order < this.length; field_order++){
            var current_field = _.find(this, function(template_element){
                return template_element.field_order == field_order;
            });
            if (!current_field.datum && (current_field.datum != 0)){
                current_field.datum = "";
            }
            var required_padding_amount = current_field.required_length - current_field.datum.toString().length;
            assert(required_padding_amount >= 0, "invalid length on " + current_field.description);
            //assert(current_field.type == typeof current_field.datum, "datum types don't match");
            for (var padding = ''; padding.length < required_padding_amount;)
                padding += ' ';
            if (current_field.type == "string"){
                current_field.padded_datum = current_field.datum + padding + ';';
            }
            else {
                current_field.padded_datum = padding + current_field.datum + ';';
            }
            buffer_data += current_field.padded_datum;
        }
        buffer_data += '\r\n';//buffer newline
    }, this.template_in_use);

    //console.log(buffer_data);

    write_buffer = new Buffer(buffer_data, 'utf8');
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(this.filename);
    file.write(write_buffer);
    file.end();

}
```

For **Program A**, the only post requests that would be happening at the time come from this: (req_calls is an array of objects that share the same key/value pairs)

```
function exportReqCalls(req_calls){
    if (req_calls.length == 0){
        return;
    }

    exported_req_calls = JSON.stringify(req_calls);

    var post_options = {
        host: config.eton_agent.host,
        port: config.eton_agent.port,
        path: '/eton_call',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': exported_req_calls.length
        }
    };

    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        logger.info("STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            //console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    post_req.on('error', function(e){
        logger.error('ReqCall not sent. Please ensure connectivity to eton-agent.js. Error Message: ' + e.message);
    });

    post_req.write(exported_req_calls);
    post_req.end();   
}
```

Comment: Are you, by any chance, failing to finish the HTTP requests properly so you get an accumulation of open TCP sockets and eventually you exhaust some system resource related to networking?  If you posted your node.js code, we could have a better look.

Comment: added some of the node.js code. As for your remark about exhausting a system resource related to networking, I do believe this is the case, but the last time we had the problem and we ran a netstat we didn't see anything out of the ordinary. Unfortunately, my knowledge of networking is really being tested at this point; I don't know what other metrics to look at.

Comment: Any chance you're leaking a file handle or some other system resource in `reqCalls_writer.write_file(req.body);`?  I'm also a bit surprised, there's no error handling or async handling for writing to a file.

Comment: No, I suppose there isn't. My understanding is that if there is an error, and that error is thrown and not handled, the program simply crashes, not so? Either way, it's probably something I should implement at some point, but how could this affect the network? How would I check such a file handle in the future?

Comment: It depends.  Exceptions thrown in async callbacks may just abort that operation and not crash the server since they don't propagate up to the top level.  Any recurring leak of a system resource can mess things up.  I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you included so far so I'm asking about the other code involved in this operation (where you write to a file) that you have not yet shown.  If you want to show that code, I can look at it too.

Comment: I added the code for writing files, just in case.

Comment: Well, I don't know if this leads to your symptoms or not, but if you have multiple requests in flight at the same time, you can end up with conflicts trying to write to the same file which would, at best, lead to unhandled errors or at worst it could cause other system issues.  You could see if this is happening to you or not by adding `file.on('error', ...);`